# How can I load a txt file in matrix form as a float type?

Tags: python

I have a txt file consisting of a 159 * 29 matrix.

I want to take this matrix as a float and store it in np.array format.

The problem is that my text file contains [,].

Let me show you some of my text files as examples. Please help. Thank you.

```
    ex.txt

    [[1.31884812e-01 4.85885328e-02 5.17866485e-02 9.24929814e-02
    9.42103216e-02 8.50022142e-02 8.57238412e-02 9.96234015e-02
    1.14856198e-01 1.11659724e-01 9.72807538e-02 9.20717962e-02
    9.12622858e-02 9.68798360e-02 1.12404521e-01 1.13864315e-01
    1.05420802e-01 1.01923343e-01 9.82294570e-02 9.85429105e-02
    1.06702456e-01 1.12663644e-01 1.19183466e-01 1.14763882e-01
    1.05617832e-01 1.02883940e-01 9.24510572e-02 8.78869806e-02
    9.66031440e-02 9.68025400e-02 1.01009777e-01 1.51004856e-01
    1.26032222e-01 4.83166563e-02 5.56340695e-02 8.56342866e-02
    8.71916453e-02 9.30664908e-02 1.00653943e-01 1.06950373e-01
    9.98731406e-02 9.03583575e-02 1.00146412e-01 1.10677896e-01
    1.09498884e-01 1.06648914e-01 1.10096858e-01 1.10210797e-01
    1.03439199e-01 1.03742909e-01 1.01274575e-01 9.87265900e-02
    1.08099849e-01 1.05718825e-01 9.43474858e-02 9.37020526e-02
    9.37328738e-02 9.00777858e-02 9.18707559e-02]
    [1.27356767e-01 9.50714549e-03 3.51917853e-02 5.60814608e-02
    4.67684941e-02 4.37193897e-02 3.94782008e-02 5.10511578e-02
    6.00998918e-02 6.40744212e-02 4.29009335e-02 5.26423953e-02
    4.14972762e-02 5.27328912e-02 5.29212138e-02 6.73998829e-02
    4.36410294e-02 5.64574948e-02 4.82356819e-02 4.65436714e-02
    5.58660110e-02 5.69371838e-02 6.07319187e-02 6.36302760e-02
    5.00506026e-02 5.59908535e-02 4.59377176e-02 4.20365157e-02
    4.84277908e-02 5.26725503e-02 4.13320813e-02 9.17620584e-02
    1.30050386e-01 5.62320480e-03 4.76918484e-02 4.19101014e-02
    4.46161651e-02 4.69018429e-02 4.94103807e-02 5.88036867e-02
    5.35074724e-02 3.88601964e-02 5.39223099e-02 5.59319300e-02
    5.42011542e-02 5.30993292e-02 5.70689604e-02 5.82497387e-02
    5.27066529e-02 5.17498580e-02 5.38496575e-02 4.50412685e-02
    5.53325257e-02 5.82311744e-02 4.09089357e-02 5.18904344e-02
    4.73671715e-02 4.49264348e-02 4.76753951e-02]
    [1.19440276e-02 1.74260751e-02 3.50030488e-03 1.25507823e-03
    6.39962770e-04 7.58302240e-05 3.95251462e-04 1.09434956e-03
    3.19130608e-04 1.10887705e-03 1.69392836e-03 5.28743182e-04
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The data isn't suitable to be read as csv, so some conversion is in order...

This assumes that there are line-breaks in the text as you have it in the example above.

```
>>> row_list = []
>>> row_data = []
>>> 
>>> for line in open("ex.txt", 'r'):
...     if '[' in line:
...         # New row.
...         row_data = []
...         row_list.append(row_data)
...         line = line.replace('[', '')
...     elif ']' in line:
...         line = line.replace(']', '')
...     vals = line.split()
...     row_data.extend(float(val) for val in vals)
>>>
```

I don't see a Pandas or numpy tag on the question, so I didn't include any code to put the resulting array into a dataframe.

`row_list` will be a list of lists of 59 items. Not what was stated in the question, but this is because each list defined in the input text has 59 items. If you're using numpy or pandas, you can reshape your dataframe or np array after you create it from the row data.

Another way to convert the input text into a list of lists. I'm not a fan of pulling whole files into memory before processing them, but this should work:

```
>>> txt = open("ex.txt", 'r').read()
>>> 
>>> txt = re.sub(r"([\de\-\.]+|\])", r"\1,", txt.strip())
>>> data = eval(txt)
>>> data = data[0]  # In case a tuple-of-lists-of-lists was returned.
>>>
>>> del txt   # Free up memory the file text was taking up.
```

data should then be a list of lists of float values. This approach fixes the syntax of the whole string so it will become a list of lists when `eval()` is called.

---

**"The numbers look weird, there's something wrong..."**

I've seen this more than once where submitted answers are assumed to be wrong because the numbers aren't displayed in the dataframe or array exactly as they appear in textual input. So this deserves some explanation.

There are alternative ways to display the same value. If the data type of the values in a dataframe is float, the interpreter (and maybe the module) decides the best way to represent their values when displayed. If the input text is `'1.45e-04'`, the interpreter may choose to display it as `0.000145`. Both represent the same float value; they are just alternative forms.

Suppose that we have some text that we want to use to construct a dataframe. One may expect that their dataframe will look the same as the input data.

```
>>> arr = """
...       foo             bar
...       1.31884812e-01  9.24929814e-02
...       9.42103216e-02  9.96234015e-02
...       1.14856198e-01  9.20717962e-02
...       """
```

So, reading the data in to the dataframe like so...

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(arr), sep=r'\s+', dtype=str)
>>> df
              foo             bar
0  1.31884812e-01  9.24929814e-02
1  9.42103216e-02  9.96234015e-02
2  1.14856198e-01  9.20717962e-02
```

It looks like everything is right. Notice that `dtype=str` had to be used to preserve the formatting of these values as strings. But that's not very useful if any calculations need to be made with these values.

```
>>> df.dtypes
foo    object
bar    object
dtype: object
```

So, we want a dataframe with floats...

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(arr), sep=r'\s+')
>>> df
        foo       bar
0  0.131885  0.092493
1  0.094210  0.099623
2  0.114856  0.092072
```

'Oh no.. the data got corrupted!'... no, that's how those values are supposed to look. It's the same set of values converted to the appropriate data type.

```
>>> df.dtypes
foo    float64
bar    float64
dtype: object
```

'But I've seen it work before where the numbers weren't changed'.. If the numbers are sufficiently small, then the interp (or module) will choose to also display the values using scientific notation and it will appear the same way as float values in the dataframe as it did in the input text.

```
>>> arr = """
...       foo             bar
...       1.31884812e-08  9.24929814e-08
...       9.42103216e-08  9.96234015e-08
...       1.14856198e-08  9.20717962e-08
...       """
>>> df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(arr), sep=r'\s+')
>>> df
            foo           bar
0  1.318848e-08  9.249298e-08
1  9.421032e-08  9.962340e-08
2  1.148562e-08  9.207180e-08
```

Notice, that the exponent in this last example is -8. This represents 10 to the -8 power, which means the decimal is shifted left that many times. The interpreter doesn't want to display that many 0's, so it chooses to use scientific notation, so it looks like the input text by coincidence.

It may look like we lost some precision with the way the values are displayed in the dataframe, but we haven't. The interpreter just isn't showing you the same number of digits as the input text did.

If you want some control over how these values are displayed in reports or diagrams, then you can convert them to strings and use string formatting to choose the number of decimal places to display and whether the data will be in scientific notation or not.

Or just convert the dataframe to `str` if you only need it for presentation and not calculation.

```
>>> df.astype(str)
              foo             bar
0  1.31884812e-08  9.24929814e-08
1  9.42103216e-08  9.96234015e-08
2  1.14856198e-08  9.20717962e-08
```

Comment: First of all, use numpy or pandas. Sorry for not tagging.
And in the first your code, row_data is read as a list not a float. And when I print row _data, very strange values such as [0.000504691383, 0.0173554273, 0.00254911564] appear. Can I ask a little more about this?

Comment: If the input text for a float value has, for instance `7.5e-04`, it's going to be a value like 0.00075 when evaluated by the interpreter. If you put the values into np or pandas, it'll probably be displayed with sci-notation  in the form `7.5e-04`, they represent the same value - just displayed differently.

Comment: @InsungLee, if you want to see values in scientific notation: `print(f"{row_list[0][0]:.8E}")`